# Putting two images right after a particular text

Tags: math-mode, graphics, amsmath

I know how to get two images side by side within minpages environment. Suppose I have a paragraph followed by the two side by side images and an equation about two or three lines. The issue I'm having is even when I put the code in the right place after the paragraph, I still get the two side by side images after the equation. How can I adjust the order the way I want. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Presumably you have those images in a `figure` environment, so see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/ (also related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. those two links have exactly what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use nested `minipage` environments. Use one "outer" `minipage` of width `\textwidth`. Then, in this `minipage`, place two half-width `minipage` environments, one per graph, and use `\captionof` statements to generate the captions. Then, below the pair of "inner" `minipage` environments, but still inside the "outer" `minipage`, use a suitable multi-line display math environment.

Here's an MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{caption,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{f1}
\captionof{figure}{First graph}
\end{minipage}\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textdwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{f2}
\captionof{figure}{Second graph}
\end{minipage}

\begin{align} % or some other multi-line displayed equation env.
a &= b+c \\
  &= d+e \\
  &= f+g
\end{align} 
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```